# Changing a Javascript's Script Id to Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi, I am building this scroll box that has a built in hidden drop down list. Well, not actually a drop down list but acts like one. My problem is I can't figure out how to change the javascript's script from an ID to a CLASS. This way I can use that javascript on all the items listed inside the scroll box. For now I just have the javascript's script embeded in the html doc than as a link.

*This is what it looks like so far:*

**Javascript in header**

```
<script>
function unhide(divID) { 
    var item = document.getElementById(divID); 
    if (item) {  item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden'; }  
} 
< /script >
```

**Code in question**

```
<ol align="center" style="font-weight: bold">Item</ol><!--Box Title-->
<div id="f1" style="height: 80px; width: 150px; overflow: scroll; border: 9px groove #FFC400"><!--scroll box-->

<!--subject 1-->
<div>
    <a href="javascript:unhide('learnHTML');">Name1 </a>
</div>
<div id="LearnHTML" class="hidden">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""> info/description </a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="">CLICK HERE TO PLAY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--subject 2-->
<a href="javascript:unhide('learnHTML');">Name2 </a>
<div>
<div id="LearnHTML" class="hidden">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""> info/description </a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="">CLICK HERE TO PLAY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--subject 3-->
    <a href="javascript:unhide('learnHTML');">Name3 </a>
    <div>
        <div id="LearnHTML" class="hidden">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""> info/description </a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="">CLICK HERE TO PLAY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!--End Scroll Box-->
</div>
```

So, all listed items' drop down list, listed items inside scroll box, are hidden until the listed item is click upon. Also, by clicking on the same listed item again it will hid its drop down once again.

Basically, I want all the listed items in the scroll box to act the same as the first listed item does. But, I cannot figure out how to change the Javascript's Id to a class to make this work.

I tried changing the Javascript's Id to a class on my own, by doing this:

```
< script >
function unhide(divClass) {  var item = document.getElementByClassName(divClass);  if (item) {  item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';  }  } < /script >
```

Then I changed the `id="LearnHTML"` to `class="LearnHTML"`, but it didn't worked. So, does anyone knows how to go about in making it work?

**CSS for the listed items:**

```
.hidden { display: none;}
.unhidden { 
    display: block; 
    background-color:orange;
    font: white;
    align:left
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting broken HTML to make it show, post well-formatted HTML, highlight it, and click the code sample **`{}`** button above the edit area.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; [read the editing help page, and reformat your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You should notice that `document.getElementByClassName` throws an error since it doesn't exist. The correct method is `.getElementsByClassName`, which returns a node collection.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even realized that. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, the letter casing does matter, I believe. The Javascript has to match the HTML.
- IDs must be unique. You can have only one ID in an html document. That is why the others weren't working.
- Using the class won't work, because you can't specify which one to toggle. It will toggle all of them, and the code will need to be a bit more complex to handle multiple classes.

So using the unhide method that takes the DivID, change the IDs from `"LearnHTML"` to `"LearnHTML1"`, `"LearnHTML2"`, `...`, and make sure the toggle links match the case.

By the way, for your information, you can't have two methods with the same name. Javascript doesn't support overloads.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arlen22/tZdfx/2/